# PHP/HTML syntax error

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

first time asking questions here. I am trying to create a small, primitive forum. I am basing it on [this](http://phpeasystep.com/workshopview.php?id=13): while making changes to it where it is needed.

So far, I have setup the database and all that. Now I am trying to fix the view_topic.php and it is returning `"Notice: Undefined index: id" on line 30 something.`
This is line 30: `$id=$_GET['id']`;

Comment: Your first time asking a question has yet to come.

Comment: `I will proberally need more help so I'd appriciate anyone refreshing once in a while.` I think you meant to go to a chatroom. Conversational debugging assistance is not suited to a programming Q&A.

Comment: I guess I was a little unspecific, I wonder what is causing this and hopefully how to fix it. I am new to PHP.

Comment: @AndyLester No, `$_GET` is correct.

Comment: How can I add whole code? I was trying to do that for some time and it kept failing.

Comment: @user1868565: Did you perform a search for the contents of the notice text, and find out what it means?

Comment: `How can I add whole code?` You don't. You post the [complete, minimal example](http://sscce.org/) that you've been using in your debugging today when narrowing down the problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I did, but I did not quite understand it I guess what I am hoping for is for someone to help me understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure `id` is a valid index before accessing it.

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

Comment: was just about to type this same answer. +1

Comment: No, all you've done is moved the problem elsewhere, since we have not been given a confirmation that the lack of this value is an acceptable case. Since `id` is a querystring parameter in the OP's example, I'm going to go ahead and suggest that it is not.

Comment: It stopped the error message, but as @LightnessRacesinOrbit said its returning nothing, I gave up on adding my code to stackoverflow, here is pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g7QC0kDv

Comment: @user1868565: I already instructed you not to post "whole code", but instead your _complete, minimal example_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand, but I guess the whole code might be useful here? The "$id" is being used at several occasions, the connection part goes fine.

Comment: @user1868565: The whole code is completely useless when you have narrowed down your problem to an isolated five/six-line program. There is zero reason that _we_ need to extract the problem from known-working SQL-related code; _you_ should do that work for us (well, it's still for _you_!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I see what you mean now, well it's from line 21-26 on that pastebin link. I changed it to what Vulcan posted and the error message does not appear anymore, but now it is not returning anything whilst echoing it.

Comment: @user1868565: That's for the reason that I wrote in my first comment to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice: Undefined index:

This means that a piece of code attempts to access an element of an array that does not exist.

So, for example:

```
$myArray = Array();  // an empty array
echo $myArray['id']; // print 'id' element

// ^^ Oops! No such element yet!
```

The `$_GET` array contains the arguments from the *querystring*, which is the `?id=1` part of your request URL.

You will need to find out why this does not contain the element with key `'id'` when `id` was provided in the URL, and then make your code decide what to do in the case that this value is missing, using a function such as `isset` or `array_key_exists` and an `if` statement.

Most likely you will present a more useful error message and terminate the script, if your code cannot continue without a valid `id` value.

Comment: **Pedant alert:** `isset` is a language construct, not a function; however, it is documented as a function since it is damn well close enough.

Comment: The `$_GET` array would also contain *all* form data *if* the form used `method="get"`.

Comment: @toxalot: That's because a form with `method="get"` leads to a URL with the form data emplaced in the querystring.

Comment: *I* understand that, but a new programmer *may not*. It *leads to* a URL with a query string, but that doesn't mean the form was accessed with this query string. I think new programmers find this confusing. FYI, I agree with (and upvoted) your answer and comments. I was merely attempting to clarify.

Comment: What do you mean "accessed with this query string"? It's important to use proper terminology for new programmers so that what they are learning is accurate, and I think your comments are a backwards step in that goal.

Comment: I'm not sure what terminology to use. As a self-taught programmer I often lack the terminology. I often know *how* to do something, but don't know what to *call* it. I'll try to explain. If I have a static form (for example) and visit it with the URL `http://example.com/form.html`, then I have "accessed it without a query string". But after I submit that form, then it may lead to a URL like `http://example.com/process_form.php?id=123`. Does that make sense? Is there a simple way to explain that without the example?

Comment: @toxalot: Sure; like this: a form with `method="get"` leads to a URL with the form data emplaced in the querystring. This is in fact the URL used to _submit_ that form data and the fact that you can still see it once the _response_ page has loaded is frankly little more than an after-effect; though due to the use of `GET` this is a semantically dubious way of looking at things -- forms really should not use this method.

Comment: :) OK. I perceived your first reply to me as an implication that my statement was irrelevant. I was trying to explain why it wasn't. But I see now that your response completes my original reply.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `id=` exists in the URL? Try adding the following near the top of your code.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) dumps information about a variable to your screen. In this case, it will display all the `GET` data sent from your form. This is a debugging technique so you can see if your code is receiving what you expect. If the form uses `method="post"` and `id` is a field in the form, then you will need to use `$_POST['id']` or `$_REQUEST['id']` to access it.